Changing the default installation path in Windows application programmatically In Custom Actions
The output of the setup wizard is an .msi file, when I run the file and in the installation folder selection dialog, the path that is showing there is what I want to change programmatically which is the value of the DefaultLocation in the setup project.
The default value of it is \[ProgramFilesFolder\]\[Manufacturer\]\[ProductName\].
Optimally, I want to have a sort of if else condition and specify the value accordingly.
I have a project linked to it which acts as its custom actions where I have implemented some code OnInstall, OnUninstall, etc...
I have tried something like this in my Custom Actions but it didn't work
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);

    Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"] = @"C:\FolderToInstall";
}

Is this doable in the first place?

After my test, this method is not available. During the MSI installation process, the installation path is indeed locked before the custom action is executed, so modifying TARGETDIR in the OnBeforeInstall method will not take effect.
If you want to change the default installation path, you can consider dynamically modifying the default value: [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]. Or use Microsoft's Orca tool, which can modify the Property table of the MSI file to achieve the effect.

Thank you for your answer, but my main need is to change the default value at run time and not make it static from the start. You mentioned to modify it dynamically though, how can that be done?
